# To Know TAG Name and Container Name from a Tag which was fired in google tag assistant

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

When i have two GTM containers installed in the page. How do i know which tag fired from which container?

please advise.

Regards,
Srijith Ramachandran

Comment: Do you need a programmatic solution ? Else the easiest way would be to install Ghostery or something like it and block selectively one container or the other and see which tags disappear.

Comment: Ghostery just blocks the tag. I think i have figured it out if its a GTM tag, you can go to the tag assistant and go to the specific TAG in the google tag assistant and click on the URL tab to know the GTM container from which the tag is fired.

Comment: Ghostery blocks the tag, yes. And when you have blocked one GTM container the tags therein will no longer fire, but the tags from the other GTM container will. So if you look which tags disappear after disabling one container you know which tags where contained therein.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this if you record the session:

1. In Tag Assistant window, on the bottom left click "Record"
2. refresh your page.
3. In Tag Assistant window on the bottom right click "View Recordings" -> "Show Full Report"
4. Tag Assistant Report will show, in here select UA tag you want to inspect
5. expand "Pageview" request (or any other request you have)
6. You can find GTM container ID in the list of variables as shown below:

[image]

As side note: this is answer to the question regarding Tag Assistant. You can find this information in standard browser developer tools under Network tab.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

It´s possible to send the container ID to Google Analytics. So you could send the IDs with every Tag you send and monitor which Container fired.

The Variable for this is called {{Conatiner ID}}

Here a example with a GA Event

[image]